# Deleting certain line of text file in python

Tags: python, text, line

I have the following text file:

```
This is my text file
NUM,123
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BACON
CAR
NUM,456
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BURGER
CAR
NUM,789
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,SAUSAGE
CAR
NUM,012
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,MEATBALL
CAR
```

And I have the following list called 'wanted':

```
['123', '789']
```

What I'm trying to do is if the numbers after NUM is not in the list called 'wanted', then that line along with 4 lines below it gets deleted. So the output file will looks like:

```
This is my text file
NUM,123
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BACON
CAR
NUM,789
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,SAUSAGE
CAR
```

My code so far is:

```
infile = open("inputfile.txt",'r')
data = infile.readlines()

for beginning_line, ube_line in enumerate(data):
    UNIT = data[beginning_line].split(',')[1]
    if UNIT not in wanted:
        del data_list[beginning_line:beginning_line+4]
```

Comment: Does your code work? If not, what is the error you get?

Comment: Your code and text say you want to delete what's __not__ in `wanted`; your example suggests otherwise.

Comment: When I do 'print ube_line' then it doesn't output the correct thing. I'm trying to write into a new file.

Comment: @ Lev Levitsky: sorry. Fixed.

Comment: Doesn't the code as is throw an error? IndexError to be exact. Since not every line has a ',' the result wont always have more than one element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't modify a list while you are looping over it.

What you could try is to just advance the iterator on the file object when needed:

```
wanted = set(['123', '789'])

with open("inputfile.txt",'r') as infile, open("outfile.txt",'w') as outfile: 
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('NUM,'):
            UNIT = line.strip().split(',')[1] 
            if UNIT not in wanted:
                for _ in xrange(4):
                    infile.next()
                continue

        outfile.write(line)
```

And use a set. It is faster for constantly checking the membership.

This approach doesn't make you read in the entire file at once to process it in a list form. It goes line by line, reading from the file, advancing, and writing to the new file. If you want, you can replace the outfile with a list that you are appending to.

Comment: Is it possible to write it back to the input file?

Comment: Not until after you read everything out of it first. What you would want to do instead is make the outfile a tempfile. Then when the whole thing is successful, you move the outfile over the infile.

Answer (score 0):

edit: deleting items while iterating is probably not a good idea, see: [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

```
infile = open("inputfile.txt",'r')
data = infile.readlines()
SKIP_LINES = 4
skip_until = False

result_data = []
for current_line, line in enumerate(data):
    if skip_until and skip_until < current_line:
        continue

    try:
        _, num = line.split(',')
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
       if num not in wanted:
           skip_until = current_line + SKIP_LINES
       else:
           result_data.append(line)
```

... and `result_data` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the code; for instance, `data_list` isn't even defined. If it's a `list`, you can't `del` elements from it; you can only `pop`. Then you use both `enumerate` and direct index access on `data`; also `readlines` is not needed.

I'd suggest to avoid keeping all lines in memory, it's not really needed here. Maybe try with something like (untested):

```
with open('infile.txt') as fin, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as fout:
   for line in fin:
       if line.startswith('NUM,') and line.split(',')[1] not in wanted:
           for _ in range(4):
               fin.next()
       else:
           fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
# find the lines that match NUM,XYZ
nums = re.compile('NUM,(?:' + '|'.join(['456','012']) + ")")
# find the three lines after a nums match
line_matches = breaks = re.compile('.*\n.*\n.*\n')
keeper = ''
for line in nums.finditer(data):
    keeper += breaks.findall( data[line.start():] )[0]
```

result on the given string is

```
NUM,456
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BURGER

NUM,012
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,MEATBALL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind building a list, and iff your `"NUM"` lines come every 5 other line, you may want to try:

```
keep = []
for (i, v) in enumerate(lines[::5]):
    (num, current) = v.split(",")
    if current in wanted:
        keep.extend(lines[i*5:i*5+5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to think of this in terms of building up a list and removing stuff from it while you loop over it. That way leads madness.

It is much easier to write the output file directly. Loop over lines of the input file, each time deciding whether to write it to the output or not.

Also, to avoid difficulties with the fact that not every line has a comma, try just using `.partition` instead to split up the lines. That will always return 3 items: when there is a comma, you get (before the first comma, the comma, after the comma); otherwise, you get (the whole thing, empty string, empty string). So you can just use the last item from there, since `wanted` won't contain empty strings anyway.

```
skip_counter = 0
for line in infile:
    if line.partition(',')[2] not in wanted:
        skip_counter = 5
    if skip_counter:
        skip_counter -= 1
    else:
        outfile.write(line)
```