# Delete a certain line in text file if user input string matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

If that `string` input by User exists in text file, the program should find/`return` **line number** in text file and `print` the `line number`

kw is the user input btw

some code for reference:

```
def DELITEM():
            kw = Dele.get()
            with open('notify.txt') as f:
                if kw in f.read:
                    print('the number of the line kw is in')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting certain line of text file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116752/deleting-certain-line-of-text-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like:

```
with open('notify.txt', 'r') as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f):
        if kw==line:
            print(num)
```

Here `enumerate()` adds a counter to the file that allows you to identify lines.

Answer (score 0):

you could loop through the lines until you find it with `readlines`

```
DELITEM():
    kw = Dele.get() 
    with open('notify.txt', 'r') as f:
        if kw in f.read:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                if kw in lines[i]:
                    print("The line is",i)
                    break
```

---

To delete the line from the text file, on way would be to delete the line in the list then write the lines back onto the file. So something like this

```
del lines[i]
```

then have another with where you write

```
with open('notify.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

so putting this altogether you have

```
DELITEM():
        lines = []
        kw = Dele.get() 
        with open('notify.txt', 'r') as f:
            if kw in f.read:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for i in range(len(lines)):
                    if kw in lines[i]:
                        print("The line is",i)
                        del lines[i]
                        break
        with open('notify.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: But the problem isn't exactly finding the line, the problem is that I have no idea how to delete the line from the text file